# how to validate mongodb embedded document

Tags: mongodb, validation, embedded-documents

MongoDB 3.2 has this nice [validation feature](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document-validation/). However, in this doc it only shows me how to do the validation on first level fields. If I have the following embedded document to insert, how could I set the validation rule?

```
{"name": {
          "first_name": "xx",
          "last_name": "yy"
         }
}
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work,

```
db.createCollection( "name_collection",
    { validator: { $and:
        [
            {name.first_name: {$type: "string"}},
            {name.last_name: {$type: "string"}}
        ]
    }
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the test codes, it works well

```
> db.createCollection('name', {validator: {$and: [{"name.first_name": {$type: 'string'}}, {"name.last_name": {$type: 'string'}}]}})
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

It seems you should add `""` to `name.last_name`,

Test it with valid data

```
> db.name.insert({name: {first_name: 'xx', last_name: 'yy'}})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Test it with invalid data

```
> db.name.insert({name: {first_name: 'xx', last_name: 3}})
WriteResult({
        "nInserted" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 121,
                "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
        }
})

> db.name.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56e8b644f33ed6e7f3c57f90"), "name" : { "first_name" : "xx",
"last_name" : "yy" } }
```

Comment: also, do you think it's possible to have $or in type? such as "first_name" can be type "string" or "null"?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have couple errors in your code snippet.

Your db.createCollection doesn't have matching braches. It should look like

```
db.createCollection("name_collection", {
  validator: { $and:[
    {'name.first_name': {$type: "string"}},
    {'name.last_name': {$type: "string"}}
  ]}
})
```

To verify if validation is working or not, try inserting partial data

```
 db.name_collection.insert({name:{first_name:0, last_name:0}})
```

See I'm just assigning  numeric value to first_name and last_name so validation should fail.

After execution of above query, It gives following error.

```
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 121,
        "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
    }
})
```

But if I assign text as pasted below, insertion should succeed which does.

```
db.name_collection.insert({name:{first_name:'f_name', last_name:'l_name'}})
```

Result:

```
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Hope this is what are you looking.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!